# python raise exception before yield

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to make a function that yields a value. Before anything could be done, I want to make sure function input is valid. Below code creates generator after execution. It raises exception only after **next**. Is there an elegant structure of the function which throws exception before **next**?

```
def foo(value):
    if validate(value):
        raise ValueError
    yield 1
```

Comment: show us your `validate` function

Comment: validate function is just an arbitrary one which returns True or False.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't check the `value` before using `next`, that is the whole point of using [gnerators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator), from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator):

> Each yield temporarily suspends processing, remembering the location
>   execution state (including local variables and pending
>   try-statements). When the generator iterator resumes, it picks up
>   where it left off (in contrast to functions which start fresh on every
>   invocation).

what you can do it is to check the value before using the generator

Comment: so I need to split foo into at least two functions? If valid, call a wrapper function that yields?

Comment: something like that, also you may post in the question more details about your use case if you want